# Migrating from Subversion to Git with svn2git on Windows

Tags: ruby, git, svn

I am using ruby installer to migrate from svn to git.I have encountered with an error like

```
        C:\Ruby22-x64\bin>svn2git http://[Domain Name]/svn/trunk/Projname

      1 [main] perl 2296 cygwin_exception::open_stackdumpfile: Dumping stack tra
ce to perl.exe.stackdump
      1 [main] perl 2296 cygwin_exception::open_stackdumpfile: Dumping stack tra
ce to perl.exe.stackdump
[svn-remote "svn"] unknown

command failed:
git svn fetch

C:\Ruby22-x64\bin>
```

Can anyone pls help me to resolve this.

Comment: The `svn2git` you are running is a Cygwin Perl, not Ruby. If you have an `svn2git` Ruby script in `C:\Ruby22-x64\bin` then try with `.\svn2git`.

Comment: @Kenney It is again giving same error

Comment: There are many `svn2git` scripts - which one are you using, and where is it installed? Also, you should probably run cygwin's `setup.exe` to update all packages and reboot; Perl shouldn't crash like that.

Comment: @Kenney I have followed the steps from this site [SiteName](http://www.troyhunt.com/2014/08/migrating-from-subversion-to-git-with.html)

Comment: Ok - try `svn2git.bat`, which should be in `C:\Ruby22-x64\bin`. I'm pretty sure it's a `%PATH%` problem.

Comment: @Kenney I have given the correct path

Comment: So `C:\Ruby22-x64\bin\svn2git.bat http://[Domain Name]/svn/trunk/Projname` gives you a cygwin perl crash?

Comment: @Kenney yes , I is giving same error

Comment: That's baffling. Try renaming your `C:\cygwin` or `C:\cygwin64` directory to something else temporarily to make sure it isn't used.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know why `git svn init` (which this script was supposed to call) didn't do this, but you can do it yourself; put this in your `.git/config`:

```
[svn-remote "svn"]
    fetch = trunk:refs/remotes/svn/master
    url = http://[Domain Name]/svn/trunk/Projname
```